# I need to have an azure_databricks job fail on an exception and it's not doing that

Tags: azure-databricks

I've written a "CriticalException" handler to handle cases where my notebook has created unusable data or some other error has happen below. My intention is to have the notebook's execution halt with a "failed" status but it's not doing that.

**What am I missing in my routine?**

This method is defined in a "helper" notebook I "run" from all my notebooks. This method gets called but the notebook continues to execute and finishes with a success status instead of halting with a failed status.

```
def CriticalException(err_msg):
  sys.stderr.write(err_msg) 
  raise RuntimeError(err_msg)
  return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, a parent routine was trapping exceptions.